# Find sequence by adding 5 or multiplying by 3

Tags: javascript

I wrote this little JavaScript function that starts with the number 1 and continually either adds 5 or multiplies by 3. This function tries to find a sequence of additions and multiplications that find that number.

Keep in mind, this function does not necessarily find the shortest sequence of operations.

I am looking for a review of my code and possible ways to make it more optimized. I'm also open to suggestions about how I can go about having this function find the shortest sequence of operations.

My code:

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

Test:

```
print(findSequence(178));
```

Output:

> ```
> ((((((((((((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) + 5) + 5)
> ```

Comment: Your code contains an invalid test and your test contains an exact copy of your code. Is this intended/your real code?

Comment: Have a look on difference between DFS and BFS. You are now using DFS and if you want the shortest sequence, I would recommend using BFS.

Comment: Fun fact: it's not his code. It's from Eloquent Javascript, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is a bit related to [a previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49418/determining-if-an-answer-can-be-generated/49441). I will give you the same advice I did to the asker of the previous question.

#### Work from the other direction.

Currently, you're branching out starting from 1 trying to reach 178. Instead, start from 178 and try to reach 1. I'll show you how that will make the problem *a lot* easier.

- We're at 178. Can we divide by 3? 178 mod 3 != 0 so no. Instead we reduce by 5.
- 178 - 5 == 173. Can we divide by 3? 173 mod 3 != 0 so no, we reduce by 5 instead.
- 173 - 5 == 168. Can we divide by 3? 168 mod 3 == 0 so yes, we can. Let's do that.
- 168 / 3 == 56. Wait a minute... this number ends with a `6`... Interesting. `(56 - 1) mod 5` equals zero, so from here we can just reduce by 5 until we've reached our target of 1.

Instead of branching out in an exponential manner, we've reduced the problem to a linear approach. Simply by flipping things backwards.

Let's say that we don't want to do the end loop of reducing by 5 just because we can (we want the shortest path, right?), then I see no other solution than to branch out recursively. When checking for the division by 3, a lot of branches are removed so it will be possible to find the shortest path by branching.

I'll leave the fun part of implementing this up to you :)

#### Some comments about your current code

(Which, given the comments above you should remove and completely re-write using the "backwards" approach)

In Java at least, it's recommended to add braces for each `if`. Also, as you're using `return` inside each `if` there's no need for `else`.

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal) {
      return history;
    }
    if (start > goal) {
      return null;
    }
    return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

I would also add a parameter to allow switching the `start` value, it will make it more flexible very easily.

I think it's good that you're hiding the `find` method inside the other function.

Comment: "'ll leave the fun part of implementing this up to you :)" Fun is the least of the words I'd use to describe this problem. Solving the problem in reverse is a total pain in the ass in terms of reversing the "history" string you've built up.

Comment: Okay, after cooling off a bit and trying this again, I figured out that I can get a string in prefix notation (e.g., * 3 + 5 * 3 1) if I work in reverse, so then all I need to do is convert it to infix notation.